# python snowflake connector execute returns early

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the python snowflake connector to send execute sql statements. I have two statements that I execute. The first is a COPY INTO from external stage. The second is a MERGE from the staging table into the next schema. Last night, on several large data sets, the MERGE began before the COPY INTO had completed (and so no data to merge). I ran this in VS Code in debug mode, and the cursor.execute(copy_sql) waited until complete before proceeding:
query: [COPY INTO CCOCLAIMLINEALL (CLAIMNBR,CLAIMLINENBR,CLAIMSTATUS,CLAIMSTARTDATE,CLAI...]
[2021-05-20T17:20:18.036Z] query execution done
[2021-05-20T17:21:01.784Z] closed

What am I missing? Why is the cursor.execute(copy_sql) returning before completion?

Comment: Is it possible to share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add a check in your code to see if the first statement is still running.

This is described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-check-query-status)